# What do these .htaccess commands do?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm creating a new website, so I'm creating a new .htaccess for it.
To get an example, I took a look at another website I have, and found the following code, among some other code, inside:

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>

<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
```

What is the purpose of these commands? should I implement them in my new site as well?

Comment: You should never implement something you don't understand just because it's on another website. Every site is different and has different reasons for their settings. You need to only use settings that work for your site and if you don't know what they do, then you can look it up. There is enough resources on Apache's site to help you.

Comment: I tried googling the README part but Google can't search for such an expression full of syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIMIT` defines what method(s) can be used.

```
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
```

`order deny,allow` will make the deny rule evaluated first, then it will evaluate the allow rule. The above, will tell it to deny access to everything, but then allow the `GET` and `POST` methods access everything. So that is basically useless.

```
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
```

The above will deny all PUT and DELETE methods.

[This](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) link can explain what GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods are in.

As for the `IndexIgnore`

> The IndexIgnore directive adds to the list of files to hide when listing a directory. File is a shell-style wildcard expression or full filename. Multiple IndexIgnore directives add to the list, rather than the replacing the list of ignored files. By default, the list contains . (the current directory).

^Gotten from the [Apache documents](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore)